# Why is the 'explicit' keyword allowing implicit conversions?

Tags: c++

```
class Test {

    private:
    int value;

    public:
    void display(void)
    {
        cout << "Value [" << value << "]" << endl;
    }
    explicit Test(int i)
    {
        value=i;
    }   
};

int main() {

    Test a(5);
    Test b(4.9);

    a.display();
    b.display();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Float value gets converted to int even though explicit is mentioned.

I was expecting (incorrectly) that float does not get converted to integer and object b not to be constructed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`explicit` refers to the constructor itself, not the **constructor's parameters**.  Your explicit constructor may not be used *as* an implicit conversion to type `Test`.

```
void function( Test param );

function( 5 ); // Your "explicit" makes this call an error.
               // The parameter must be explicitly cast, such as Test(5)
```

**In C++11 or later**, you can prevent implicit parameter conversions using the `= delete` syntax on a template parameter.

```
  Test(int i)
  {
      value=i;
  }   

  template<typename T>
  Test(const T&) = delete;
  // ^ Aside from your int constructor and the implicitly-generated 
  // copy and move constructors, this will be a better match for any other type
```

**In C++20 or later**, you can prevent implicit parameter conversions using the [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as) concept.

```
  Test(std::same_as<int> auto i)
  {
      value=i;
  }
```

Comment: very nice trick! +1 You should also mention that the copy ctor is still implicitly generated

Comment: @vsoftco it's valid for non-member functions too.

Comment: yes, I realized that, it is purely based on template overload resolution

Comment: And if you don't have C++11 you can get a similar effect with `template<typename T> Test(const T&) { T::error(); }`.

Answer (score 4):

`explicit` just prevents any implicit conversions. So if you had:

```
void foo(Test t);
```

You cannot call `foo(4);` because the `Test` constructor is `explicit`. You'd have to call `foo(Test(4));`. The `explicit` keyword has nothing to do with any conversions that might have to happen during construction.

From the standard [class.conv.ctor]:

> An explicit constructor constructs objects just like non-explicit constructors, but does so **only** where the
>   direct-initialization syntax (8.5) or where casts (5.2.9, 5.4) are **explicitly** used.

Which means that `Test t = 4;` is also illegal, but `Test t(42.0)` is fine.

Comment: In this case he can prevent the implicit conversion by using list-initialization (`Test t{42.0}`)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Only cause it narrows. I could still do `Test{'a'}`.

Comment: but is line "Test b(4.9);" not an explicit initialization? .. I had assumed that since I don't have "Test(double d)" .. this conversion from double to int would not have happened .. From your answer .. got the clarity that in stmt "Test b(4.9)" compiler casts 4.9 to 4 .. Thank you

Comment: @dpb It is an explicit initialization, yes (because you are explicitly typing `Test`). After that, the compiler is allowed to convert `double` to `int` so it accepts your code without complaint. If your one constructor happened to be `explicit Test(string )`, then you'd get a compile error on no conversion from `double` to `string`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [Floating–integral conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Floating.E2.80.93integral_conversions).
That is: it's an implicit conversion between a prvalue of type `double` to a prvalue of type `signed int`. It discards the fractional part.

TL;DR: the conversion happens between 'double' and 'int', not in your `Test` constructor. If you want to prevent that constructor to be called with a `float` or a `double` you can add the definition:

```cpp
Test(double) = delete;
```

In your `Test` class. [Live on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0Aclass+Test+%7B%0Apublic:%0A++explicit+Test(int+i)+noexcept+:+value%7B+i+%7D+%7B%7D%0A++Test(double)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++void+display()+const+noexcept+%7B+std::printf(%22value+%5B+%25d+%5D%5Cn%22,+value)%3B+%7D%0A%0Aprivate:%0A++int+value%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++Test+a(5)%0A%23if+false%0A+++++,+b(4.9f)+//+ERROR:+calls+deleted+constructor+%60Test(double)%60%0A%23else%0A+++++,+b(5)%0A%23endif%0A+++++%3B%0A++a.display()%3B%0A++b.display()%3B%0A%0A++static_cast%3Cvoid%3E+(std::getchar())%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:62.22719641857862,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1400,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!((name:fmt,ver:trunk)),options:%27-O+-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Weverything+-Wno-c%2B%2B98-compat++-Wno-c%2B%2B20-compat+-Wno-pre-c%2B%2B20-compat-pedantic%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%270%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:37.77280358142138,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)